# Getting files in Hadoop into a web application

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop. Right now I am trying to do an application in eclipse in which I want to use data present in HDFS. If we want to connect to database with Java, we have JDBC connection. Like that, what do I need to do to connect to HDFS directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hadoop, firstly, you would have to make sure that Hadoop is up and running. Apache Hadoop provides Java classes - FileSystem to access the files in HDFS from the Java application. One example is below, I am accessing /books/pg5000.txt using FileSystem and IOUtils.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;


public class FileSystemCat {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
          String uri = "/books/pg5000.txt";
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
            } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to give core-site and hdfs-site paths?

Comment: I'm telling the system where the hadoop is installed, so I am specifying the path like in JDBC connection you would need to give the IP/port of the system you are trying to connect to. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I uderstood it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate solution to access the HDFS files as records (rows) as like any other database. 
You can configure Hive with Hadoop and start HiveServer2 and then utilize Thrift API in any application to access the data reside in HDFS as Tables.

Reference link:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

Also HIVE ODBC Driver is available from several popular Hadoop distributors (Cloudera, Microsoft HDInsight, Hortonworks) as well.