# Create Directory inside HDFS using java Servlet

Tags: java, hadoop, servlets

I am building web app that can create and delete directory and files from HDFS just like Hadoop web UI.But I failed at my first step. I can't even create directory in HDFS.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.net.URI;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class Saurab extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String hdfsUri = "hdfs://saurab:9000/";
        String dirName = "ekbana113";
        FileSystem hdfs = null;
        Configuration con = new Configuration();

        try {
            con.addResource(new Path("/home/saurab/hadoopec/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            con.addResource(new Path("/home/saurab/hadoopec/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

            hdfs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsUri), con); //hdfs is null, I don't know why ?
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            hdfs.mkdirs(new Path(hdfsUri + "/" + dirName)); // Null pointer exception
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124206/getting-files-in-hadoop-into-a-web-application)
I am using tomcat server to launch my webapp. Hadoop is up and running. I created a war file and put that warfile in `/opt/tomcat/webapps/`. Then I did `saurab:8080/servlet-name/mapper-url`
Is this the right way to do, or I am doing horribly wrong ?

Comment: What is exactly your problem? You cannot access the Web app page? You are getting an exception? I doubt anyone can help without understanding exactly what is the problem...

Comment: well, that hdfs variable is null, which means FileSystem object is not being made. i was confused why is that variable null, because when I run this program as java application `FileSystem.get()` returns filesystem object and I can use hdfs features but when I do it from servlet or web app, I get null

Comment: One of the reasons it might be null, because the configurations are not being passed correctly. Have you tried setting the configurations manually instead of providing the files? Like: `con.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://example.org/");`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet does not have `@WebServlet` annotation. Did you create `web.xml`? If no, you should add `@WebServlet` annotation to your servlet or create WEB-INF/web.xml and write a URL mapping in it. In addtion, you should access to `http://saurab:8080/warfile-name/mapped-url`.

If your war file name is test1.war and you add `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/test2" })` before `public class Saurab extends HttpServlet {`, then you can access to `http://saurab:8080/test1/test2`.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I have created `web.xml`, but that didnot help either. What I did was I used `webhdfs` and it's running fine, but rather than doing `'http://saurab:50070/webhdfs/vi/dir1/dir2?op=MKDIRS"`, i wanted to do `hdfs.mkdirs();`, is it possible or I have to use webhdfs?